# onClick inside fragment giving me NPE

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, onclicklistener

I've been wrestling with this for quite a while now.

I switched from having a regular Activity to now using fragments (by users recommendations), but I've been getting the same issue.

I have 3 pages that are now 3 fragments inside of a ViewPager. I want the button with the id addSiteButton in the addSite fragment; when clicked, to scroll over to setCurrentItem(2).

Any help is appreciated! Here's my code.

The FragmentActivity

```
public class fieldsActivity extends FragmentActivity {


private static final int NUMBER_OF_PAGES = 3;

ViewPager mPager;
MyFragmentPagerAdapter mMyFragmentPagerAdapter;


/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // to create a custom title bar for activity window
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.fields);
    // use custom layout title bar
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.topbar);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.fieldspager);
    mMyFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mMyFragmentPagerAdapter);
    mPager.setCurrentItem(1);


}


private static class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int page) {

        switch (page) {

            case 0: return new settingFields();

            case 1: return new addSite();

            case 2: return new createSite();

        }

       return null;


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return NUMBER_OF_PAGES;
    }

}
```

The class with the button

```
public class addSite extends Fragment {


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }

    RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_site, container, false);
    final ViewPager mPager = (ViewPager) mRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.fieldspager);
    Button addSiteButton = (Button) mRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.addSiteButton);
    addSiteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            mPager.setCurrentItem(2, true);

        }
    });

   return mRelativeLayout;

}
}
```

I feel like I'm going in circles and not getting the desired motion.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does `R.layout.add_site` contain a ViewPager with the id `R.id.fieldspager`? Based on the fact that your Activity calls the same Id, I think not.

Comment: Please learn how to use the "logcat" utility and post the StackTrace. Or even better, read the stacktrace and check which line you have the problem at, then find out what is null on that line, and solve the problem.

Comment: @A--C
`R.layout.add_site` does not have the `R.id.fieldspager`. `R.layout.fields` does.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg
The error is happening in line `mPager.setCurrentItem(2, true);` inside of the `onClick`. I just don't know how to fix it. I'm pretty new at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply make the Fragment as a class inside the FragmentActivity and take out the variable shadowing in `onCreateView()` since your pager is a global variable.

```
public class fieldsActivity extends FragmentActivity {


  private static final int NUMBER_OF_PAGES = 3;

  ViewPager mPager;
  MyFragmentPagerAdapter mMyFragmentPagerAdapter;


  /**
   * Called when the activity is first created.
   */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // to create a custom title bar for activity window
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.fields);
    // use custom layout title bar
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.topbar);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.fieldspager);
    mMyFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mMyFragmentPagerAdapter);
    mPager.setCurrentItem(1);


  }

  public static class addSite extends Fragment {


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_site, container, false);
      //final ViewPager mPager = (ViewPager) mRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.fieldspager);
      Button addSiteButton = (Button) mRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.addSiteButton);
      addSiteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        mPager.setCurrentItem(2, true);

        }
      });

      return mRelativeLayout;

    }
  }
}
```

Also consider using the `@Override` annotation whenever you override a method so you don't make mistakes and use proper naming conventions. Java classes start with a capital.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Delete and replace the `MyFragmentPagerAdapter` with the `addSite Fragment`?

Comment: No, make `addSite` a class inside `fieldsActivity`.

Comment: Gotcha. But how are the other 2 `Fragments` able to be adjacent to each other?

Comment: @PhDeOliveira Now I'm not sure I follow, having multiple classes inside the same file does not mean they show up besides each other. If your other fragments also need `mPager` then implement the same approach, move them into `fieldsActivity`. Note that their class names need to be `public static class....` or Eclipse complains.

Comment: Ha!
Ok So if I were to move all of the other fragments I would have to take out `FragmentPagerAdapter` correct? If I'm doing it this way, am still able to swipe to different fragments?

Comment: I am pretty sure that you still need the adapter. All we're doing now is moving the fragments into the same file so they can have access to the pager and potentially avoid the NPE.

Comment: Ok looks like it worked! I had to remove a few `public static` in order to make it work. Thanks for you help! Couldn't of done it without you!